# Can't intall ng-boostrap with Angular and peer js

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to install ng bootstrap on an angular project. But when I do, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@10.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~10.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"10.2.4" from @angular/localize@10.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^10.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@8.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"8.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

But on another project, the installation went well. Can someone explain to me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try removing package.lock, node_modules and running `npm install` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I put my solution in case someone has the same problem.
I first updated angular core with `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`.
Since I had ng-starrating installed, I uninstalled it with `npm uninstall ng-starrating`.
And finally I added ng-bootstrap with `ng add @ ng-bootstrap / ng-bootstrap`. And everything is going well.